# MDL Align Switch With Its Label

Tags: html, css, material-design

As shown in the image below, my MDL switch isn't aligning with its label. The centering techniques I've tried didn't have any effect. They are:

- `margin: 0 auto`
- `display: inline-block` with `text-align: center` on the parent
- `<div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>` on either side of the form

Codepen: https://codepen.io/MrNakaan/pen/mEgdvX

Answer (score 0):

I found that I placed the `display` in the wrong spot to get the switch to fit in with the form. The form itself needs `display: inline-block;` in order to pull the switch icons into the form itself. From there, other changes can get the alignment the way you want.

Codepen with left and center alignment, comment if you can figure out right alignment: https://codepen.io/MrNakaan/pen/OXGJwk